# port number in acrylic dns proxy hosts file

Tags: dns, hosts-file

I want to map a url as follows:

127.0.0.1:8080 *.devserver.com

but windows host file neither support port number nor wildcards.So I am using acrylic dns proxy which supports wildcard.So following works nicely:

127.0.0.1 *.devserver.com

but port number is not supported with acrylic too.SO I have to browse to *.devserver.com:8080 for the desired functionality.is there a way I can use port also along with wildcards in hosts file.Any alternative to acrylic dns proxy for this ?

I need to specify port number more than wildcard.So I can compromize with wilcard and specify each subdomain in hosts file just that port number should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Rewrite Module is the traditional way

HOSTS file isn't meant for the work you're trying to make it do. Traditionally Rewrite module running on your server is used. So any requests that come in for `*.devserver.com` are silently redirected to `127.0.0.1:8080`

### How do I do it?

I am glad you asked

1) [mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)
2) [4 More ways](http://www.wikihow.com/Rewrite-a-URL)